# Hide None value of django form field

Tags: python, django

I have a end_date field on my news apps which is a facultative field.
When a author is editing one of his new and erase the end_date, I set in the model the end_date to None.

My problem is that the field then display the value 'None' on next edit instead of just being blank.

Here is my field :

**models.py**

```
end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
end_date = forms.CharField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'format': 'DD, d MM yy', 'placeholder': _('End date')}))
```

and the assignation in my view :

**views.py**

```
 if news_form.cleaned_data['end_date'] == '' :
    edited_new.end_date = None 
 edited_new.save()
```

EDIT :

here is my template :

**news.html**

```
        <form action="#" method="post" role="form" id="news-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ news_form.media }}
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <h2 class="panel-title">{% trans "Add or edit news" %}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary cancel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> {% trans "Cancel" %}</a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-btn save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span><span class="button-text"> {% trans "Save" %}</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            {{ news_form.title }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
                            {% trans 'Tag' %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
                            {{ news_form.tag }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 no-label-field redactor-field">
                            {{ news_form.message }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 date-field no-label-field">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
                                    {{ news_form.start_date }}
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 date-field no-label-field">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
                                    {{ news_form.end_date }}
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            {{ news_form.active }} {% trans 'Activate the news' %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span style="display:none;">{{ news_form.id }}</span>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the filter `default_if_none` available since Django 1.3, it'll only work for values that are `None`.

```
{{ news_form.end_date|default_if_none:'' }}
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)

Comment: It only works on value, not on form field, is it not ?

Comment: It only works on values:
{{ news_form.end_date.value|default_if_none:'' }}

Also it dosnt work with blank value. Only works if there is something inside' '
{{ news_form.end_date.value|default_if_none:'a' }} This will work

Comment: Why is the default for 'None' not '' (empty)?